# Trying to prove a theorem about convergence of a sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

The following is the problem that I am working on.

> Prove that if $\{s_n\}$ converges, then $\{|s_n|\}$ converges.

The following is the idea of the proof I'm trying to make, so it's a little loose. However, I'm not 100% sure if I'm doing it right.

proof:

If $\{s_n\}$ converges, then $\{s_n\}$ must be bounded and Cauchy, i.e, $\delta(s_n,s_m) < \epsilon$ for a large enough $n,m$.

Consider $\delta(|s_n|,s_m) $.

If $s_n > 0$ then $\delta(|s_n|,s_m) =\delta(s_n,s_m) < \epsilon$ so we are done.

And I'm stuck here. I cannot make a good argument when $s_n<o$. I can see that $\{|s_n|\}$ is bounded above by either $\sup (s_n)$ or $|\inf (s_n)|$, but I remember that boundedness doesn't guarantee convergence. $\{s_n\}$ is not necessarily monotonic either, so I was wondering what I could do.

Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the reverse triangle inequality, we have that $||s_n| - |s_m|| \leq |s_n - s_m|$. Thus your sequence of absolute values is Cauchy as well, so it converges.

Comment: @hyg17:  Note that the same idea works without Cauchy. Let $s$ be the limit of the sequence $(s_n)$. Then since $||s_n|-|s||\le |s_n-s|$, we conclude that $|s|$ is the limit of the sequence $(|s_n|)$.

Comment: @AGM: After graduating college and teaching math for 4 years, I have never even thought about using that. It really helps. Thanks!

Comment: @AndréNicolas I was thinking that, too. But I wasn't sure if they would be the same limits because I couldn't prove convergence in the first method.

Comment: You prove convergence by the variant I mentioned by noting that by the definition of limit, for any $\epsilon$ there is an $N$ such that $|s_n-s|\lt \epsilon$ if $n\gt N$. By the inequality, if $n\gt N$ (same $N$) we have $||s_n|-|s||\lt \epsilon$. What we have actually done is proved *continuity* of the function $|x|$.